# Generate .key file from .pem file

Tags: ssl, openssl, pem, jks

I have been given .jks, me.pem and me-key.pem file. How can I generate .key file from it?

I tried various ssl commands but they ask for a passpharse / password.

Do I need to get its passpharse from the provider?

Thanks

Comment: Yep, you need passpharse.

Comment: Thanks. Could this be stored in me-key.pem file? Is there anyway to extract it?

Comment: http://asaf.github.io/blog/post/export_certificate_and_private_key_from_jks/